# Obspy spectrogram ValueError (noverlap must be less than n)

Tags: python, valueerror, spectrogram, obspy

I working with seismic data using obspy and I want to get a spectrogram for my data. When I apply the spectrogram function to the initial data everything works fine.

```
st.spectrogram(log=True, title='BW.RJOB ' + str(st[0].stats.starttime))
```

However when I slice and interpolate the data

```
tr = st[0]
sr=4.9999
tr2 = tr.slice(point - 20, point + 180)

tr2.interpolate(sampling_rate=sr)
```

*point is some arbitrary point in my data

*initial sampling rate is 124.99

and then perform the spectrogram

```
tr2.spectrogram(log=True, title='BW.RJOB ' + str(tr2.stats.starttime))
```

I get the following error:

*** ValueError: noverlap must be less than n

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I managed to figure out what the problem was. After interpolating the seismic wave I had a problem with the length of overlap in FFT. By looking at the documentation of the spectrogram from scipy and obspy:

[scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html)

> - npersegint, optional Length of each segment. Defaults to None, but if window is str or tuple, is set to 256, and if window is array_like,
>   is set to the length of the window.

> - noverlapint, optional
>   Number of points to overlap between segments. If None, noverlap = nperseg // 8. Defaults to None

[obspy](https://docs.obspy.org/_modules/obspy/imaging/spectrogram.html#spectrogram)

> - wlen: Window length for fft in seconds. If this parameter is too small, the calculation will take forever. If None, it defaults to (samp_rate/100.0)

The 1000 npts of my seismic trace and the 256/8=32 window of FFT caused the problem.

This raises the error in the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py)

```
if noverlap >= n:
    raise ValueError('noverlap must be less than n')
```

where n is the number of data points in each window.

So the number of data points in each window was larger than number of overlap between adjacent windows.

The **wlen=10** solved my issue. So the code is now as follows:

```
tr2.spectrogram(log=True, title='Spectrogram'),wlen=10)
```